# How to accept role names that contain spaces?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def give(ctx, member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
  member = member or ctx.message.author
  
  await member.add_roles(role)
```

This code can give a user a role but it doesn't work if the role has a space in it. How can I accept role names that contain spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add a `*` before the role parameter (Python's keyword-only argument specification). This tells discord.py to consume the rest of the command and feed it to the roles converter.

Also, it seems like you want to make the `member` parameter optional (judging from the first line in the function), this is also possible by using `typing.Optional`.

```
import typing

@client.command() 
async def give(ctx, member: typing.Optional[discord.Member] = None, *, role: discord.Role):   
    member = member or ctx.message.author
    await member.add_roles(role)
```